# How can I dynamically add values to my typescript array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically populate my pieChartColors array, so that in the end my array will look something like this:

```
public pieChartColors:Array<Color> = [
{
  backgroundColor: '#141C48'
},
{
  backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
},
{
  backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF'
},
...
]
```

I'm starting with a blank array and have tried a few different ways to get the values added, but none of them are working (my color values are stored without the hash symbol):

```
public pieChartColors: Array<Color> = [];

public buildPieChart() {
...        
    for (let pie of pieData) {
      // none of these work
      this.pieChartColors.push(backgroundColor: '#'+pie.backgroundColor);
      this.pieChartColors.backgroundColor.push('#'+pie.backgroundColor);
      this.pieChartColors['backgroundColor'].push('#'+pie.backgroundColor);
    }
...
}
```

BTW, pieData is an object I'm looping through from the database with the backgroundColor values. If I console.log the pie.backgroundColor, the value is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like in JavaScript:

```
this.pieChartColors.push({backgroundColor: '#'+pie.backgroundColor});
```